# Meaning of follow me inside, outside through the stratosphere

Tags: lyrics

It is a part of a song's lyric.

What does it mean?

...
Whatever I want I get
I want a shooting star
Whatever I need I have
When I’m with you

**Follow me inside, outside

Through the stratosphere**
The moon is shining for you
It knows that I adore you
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could mean "Follow me everywhere I go", because "inside" and "outside" together constitute "everywhere".

"Through the stratosphere" could hint on their journey to outer space. They are inside (on Earth), they travel through the stratosphere, and they are outside (in space).